# Protractor- Changing ControlFlow to async-await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, jasmine, protractor

Following is the our spec file which works fine without async keyword.

[image]

However when we trying to change our existing protractor framework from control flow to async-await its showing above error in both describe and it block. Even we tried using 'async () =>'. Its really frustrating

Comment: I think you shouldn't put the `async` keyword in the `describe` function, only use it in each `it` block. And also try switching to ES6 arrow function syntax, to look like this: `describe('Projects CRUD', () => {`

Answer (score 2):

A more detailed explanation would be that `describe` bloks are just used for grouping. And `async` functions are 'syntactic sugar for returned promise chains', and `describe` blocks often do not support (as in waiting for resolution of) returned promises.
Also it's better practice to put all `require` declarations outside those `describe` blocks. I would reorganize that code like the following and try again:

```
const projectsPage = require('../pages/Projects_Page.js');
const commonFunctions = require('../utils/CommonFunctions.js');

describe('Projects CRUD', () => {
    it('Rename Project - Duplicate name check', async () => {
        //your code here  
    });
});
```

Comment: If i use async keyword for it block then its showing 'invalid arrow function parameters' error.

Comment: then try switching back to normal function syntax, but keep the async only in the `it` blocks

Comment: you might also want to add the keyword `await` before calling each function inside the `it` block

Answer (score 1):

Test framework like Jasmine, Mocha contains these keyword such as describe, before,beforeEach and so on. Test framework has inbuilt definition of order of execution these block.
For describe and It block the function definition is

```
export const describe: {
    /**
    * Registers a new test suite.
    * @param name The suite name.
    * @param fn The suite function, or {@code undefined} to define a pending test suite.
    */
    (name: string, fn: Function): void;


 export const it: {
/**
 * Add a test to the current suite.
 * @param name The test name.
 * @param fn The test function, or {@code undefined} to define a pending test case.
 */
(name: string, fn: Function): void;
```

It means describe and it block takes two parameter. Name and function. In case of describe you don't need to use async/await because this function internally uses 'return'. Hence it will wait for entire thing is finished inside describe block. In other way if you just write async in describe block then you will have to write await under describe function which is not required.

In case of It block you will have to write like async function() {} because you have to wait on steps written under it block. Refer following example.

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
  it('should greet the named user', async function() {
    await browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');

    await element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys('Julie');

    var greeting = element(by.binding('yourName'));

    expect(await greeting.getText()).toEqual('Hello Julie!');
  });
```

**Note : You don't need to use await if function doesn't return Promise. It is useless. In above code snippet, there is not await before element. It means element doesn't return promise, It only returns object of ElementFinder.**